# Why are shares not settled on the same day?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, shares, settling-and-clearing

I know the settlement process but I am still confused about why trades/shares are settled on T+2nd day. Why the settlement is not done at the very moment we make the trade?

Any clarification on this will be greatly helpful. Thank you.